# What's the maximum amount of side quests you can complete in Majora's Mask in a 3 day cycle?

Tags: zelda-majoras-mask

How many side quests can you complete in a single 3 day cycle, after you have done all of the dungeons and have all the masks? Think of it like, how many quests can you complete in one cycle (even completed ones) before the moon falls? I'm rather curious, I know the Keifi quest takes all 3 days but you do have some time to do other quests and beat the bosses of each dungeon again during that time.

Comment: My dim memory says that one or two are mutually exclusive and can't be done on a quest maximizing run.

Comment: After getting rid of the deku mask, you can beat the entire game without going back in time again. You can probably complete all quests in a single cycle, too. Though, not the first time around, since you need quest reward items to do other quests.

Comment: Having a short list of side quests you are interested in would help narrow this down ... (should it include just the masks / bomber's notebook, or also pieces of heart / bottles / everything else?) Even once you've collected everything and have access to the whole world, there may be a few things that cannot be done on the same day.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to complete all the side quests in a single 3 day period?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/23817/is-it-possible-to-complete-all-the-side-quests-in-a-single-3-day-period)

Comment: I'm not familiar with this game, but wondering if there is a significant difference between "how many quests" and "can you complete all quests". These seem like two separate questions to me.